# How to flip element onclick button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery flip.js to flip the element. but when i click on div element  the div gets flipped. but i need to flip the element on click on flip buttton and flip back again when clicked on flip back button.

How can i do this?

```
    <div id="card-1" class="card">
  <div class="front">
      Front: Cursus aliquet mus et sociis, placerat adipiscing a placerat magnis integer nisi lacus in, turpis porttitor? Lectus nunc dis in porta, montes lacus. Tortor. Pid sit nisi eu nec aenean.
      <button id="flip-card1">Flip</button>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
      <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
      Back: Dolor scelerisque ridiculus! Mus? Augue, montes, montes proin rhoncus vel a parturient dapibus eros? Penatibus nascetur. In turpis nisi elementum nascetur habitasse augue egestas, in ac rhoncus odio porttitor turpis.
      <button id="flipback-card1">Flip Back</button>
  </div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#card-1").flip({
    axis: "y", // y or x
    reverse: false, // true and false
    trigger: "click", // click or hover
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `card-1` is the id of the div. You need to change your `id selector` from  this

```
 $("#card-1").flip({//this is the id of the div
```

to

```
 $("#flip-card1").flip({//this is the id of the button
```

You can also try

```
 $("#card-1").find('button').flip({
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with flip.js, but you can accomplish the same thing with the following...

```
$(function() {
    $("#card-1 .back").hide();
    $("#flip-card1").click(function() {
        $("#card-1 .front").hide();
        $("#card-1 .back").show();
    });
    $("#flipback-card1").click(function() {
        $("#card-1 .front").show();
        $("#card-1 .back").hide();
    });
});
```